# VBA code to select the min of an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, date

I need to select the cell containing the min value of today's date only looking at the Day. Problem is when the month rolls the macro will select 01 when I want it to select 28. My first thought was to set up the array(28, 29, 30, 31) because every month will be the same, but I still cant figure out how to select cell containing the min of that array.

So I have this list of backup codes. The last 6 numbers are reference to the date I.E. "02362113015" was backed up on 11/30/15 I only need to keep 4 days of backup, so the code needs to find the earliest date Then copy the whole code.

```
A                    B
02362113015         30
03030210115         01
02455812815         28
03604583115         31
02458182915         29
```

Thanks in advance for any hints or advice.

This is the furthest I got code wise then nothing I put in the blank made sense to me.

```
Dim cel As Range
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = H1: H5

For Each cel In Rng
    If cel = (28 Or 29 Or 30 Or 31) Then
       cel.Activate
    End If
Next
```

Comment: what about to sort both columns and get first cell in A? Did i understand your question correctly?

Comment: Please explain what you exactly doing and share the macro

Comment: Updated. Sorry If I am asking in a confusing way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a range you should set it like:

```
Set Rng = Range("H1:H5")
```

Other than that, this code works for me:

```
Sub test()


Dim cel As Range
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range("H1:H8")

For Each cel In Rng
    If cel.Value = 28 Or cel.Value = 29 Or cel.Value = 30 Or cel.Value = 31 Then
        cel.Activate
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Anything you would like to do with the cell in question should then be placed inside the If statement.

Comment: Will This code look for the lowest number first? in case 30 shows up before 28?